# Excel - Format cell showing always the first digit

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

So my question is simple, but I have trouble solving it. I want the cell to show always the first digit, no matter how long the number is - for example if I type       `0123` - it displays `0123`, and if I type `01234` - it displays `01234`. I know I can use the `0000` formula for the first example and `00000` for the second, but the length of the number is not fixed and the first digit must be always displayed since sometimes it could be `0`. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Your requirement implies that you want to treat the input as text and not as number. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Change the format of the cell to 'Text' (*before* you enter the data). Afterwards, it will always show exactly what you type.
2. type a `'` (single straight quote) in front of your input. Excel will keep the display exactly as typed (but *without* that single quote).

If you want to use the input later as a number in formulas, you can simply use VALUE() to get it converted back to a number; although Excel mostly does that automatically, even if it is a text.